# How to allow a user to access only specific projects in my solution

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using VSTS on Visualstudio.com to host our Solution. I have one solution with multiple Visual Studio projects, all hosted in a Team Project inside TFS. Now I'll have some one to help me with development, but I don't want him to have access to all the Visual Studio projects, only some of them. How can I give him access to some of the Visual Studio projects while denying access to the other ones?

Comment: You're using "project" to refer to too many things. Can you update your question to differentiate between TFS "team projects" and Visual Studio projects?

Comment: I've edited the question as you suggested

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using TFVC as source control, you can refer to these steps below:

1. Add the user to your VSTS
2. Go to the admin page of that team project
3. Select Security tab
4. Click Create group to create a new group (e.g. CodeGroup)
5. Set View project-level information to Allow in Permissions tab
6. Add the corresponding user to that group in Members tab
7. Click Version Control tab
8. Select the folder of the project (one of the project in your solution folder)
9. Click Add to add CodeGroup (step4)
10. Set Read and Check in permissions to Allow

If you are using Git as source control, you can’t set the security for an item (project in a solution) in the repository.

On the other hand, If there are some project references that the user can’t access, I recommend that you can package and push the assembly to the feed of your VSTS: [Package Management in Team Services and TFS](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/overview)