# How to restrict Devs to specific project in TFS

Tags: security, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, devops

we are using TFS in azure devops
i have a solution in visual studio 2019
and we have created a project in TFS this project is connected to the solution in vs2019

This solution has 5 projects

there are 2 admin which are currently developing these projects
now we are planning to add 2 more devs but we want to restrict new devs to only 2 projects in that solution.
for security purpose
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using TFVC as source control, you can refer to the steps below:

1. Select Security tab for the folder of the project (one of the project in your solution folder)

[image]

2. Set Read permissions for the devs to Deny.

[image]

If you are using Git as source control, you can’t set the security for an item (project in a solution) in the repository. As workaround, you can split projects into multiple repo([submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)), and then set permissions for each repo.

[image]

Here is a case with similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45984078/how-to-allow-a-user-to-access-only-specific-projects-in-my-solution) you can refer to.